# java or javascript way to convert images file to favicon.ico

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying create a java function to convert image files such as "jpg, jpeg, gif, png" into favicon.ico. Does anyone know any library can do that? I want pure java or javascript way. Not the way using imageMagick with jni

Comment: Does one still need to use those? I thought modern browsers can also use PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [image4J](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) which will allow you to create `ICO` images through Java

As simply as...

```
List<BufferedImage> listOfImages = ...;
ICOEncoder.write(listOfImages , new File("favicon.ico"));
```

You may also want to check out [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) as well...

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer: I not aiming to Answer the question in the most efficient way***, but i found an interesting possibility how to solve this problem in an unconventional manner.

with some googling i found this existing site http://mrcoles.com/favicon-creator/  (first result, for the searchterms "javascript create ico").

It has javascript code to create an ICO file, coping this code and adding some canvas html5 magic like found [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/), you could build the whole thing in Javascript and having lots of fun.

Just a crazy Javascript approach, from the do-it-yourself (copy-past-it-yourself) shelf. :)))